# HCL Notes client: any documentation available on using JavaScript in a form?

Tags: javascript, domino-designer-eclipse, hcl-notes

I'd like to know the details of how to use JavaScript in a form in the HCL Notes client (V11+): what is possible, what is supported? As an example: I know that `document.forms[]` is available, but `document.getElementById()` isn't. What else is there? TIA

Comment: I'm afraid that as asked this question is way to broad. You can add JavaScript in different locations with different effects. You question asks for listing what is possible and what not. Such lists are not well received here and usually such questions are closed.

Comment: I specifically asked for any documentation on how to use JavaScript in a form that is to be used in the Notes client. Where is that too "broad" and how could I possibly be more specific??